# How can I determine if my device supports MHL?

Tags: mhl

I'm an Android novice.  I want to determine if my Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2017) supports [MHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link).  Two obvious ways of doing this are:

1. Consult the manual.
2. Connect the tablet to an HDMI display using an MHL adapter, and try it!

But, I don't see any mention of MHL in the manual, and I don't have an MHL adapter.  Is there any way I can tell from within the Android OS if my device supports MHL?

Comment: If it is not mentioned in manual, it won't. Won't they like to publish all features ?

Comment: answer is no, after checking i can inform you that galaxy tab 8.0 2017 do not support MHL connection

Comment: A little Google search brought up the [device specs](http://www.telspecs.com/samsung/SM-T385/) which explicitly state: No MHL for this device.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try checking here first: [MHL Devices](http://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx?tid=1)

Another way is using a third party tool: [Checker for MHL (HDMI)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wikimediacom.MHLChecker&hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

your device do NOT support mhl. for almost a decade every time when i need any "obcure" info about any mobile device  i just go to [gsmarena web page](https://www.gsmarena.com/), very dependable source of information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/190029)

Comment: @wbogacz It was me who provided the link. And the details are "no support for MHL". In case you don't know the site: GSMArena lists the device specs for many devices. Makes no sense to include them all with the answer – and the essential part (no MHL support) was included already ;)